# Does Mac terminal killall command quit or force quit?

Tags: macos, unix, terminal, macos-high-sierra

What exactly do the kill and killall commands do?  I realize they terminate an application or process, but do either of them do do it cleanly/safely, like "Quit" in the UI does?  Or are they more like "Force Quit"?

Thanks!

(macOS 10.13.4 High Sierra)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `kill` command is a UNIX command (macOS is a UNIX variant) that sends signals to processes. There are many different signals that can be sent to processes. The signals have defined names and numeric codes.

If you don't specify a signal, the default will be used, which is the `TERM (15)` signal. The specification of the `TERM` signal is designed to give the addressed process a chance to shutdown gracefully, i. e. do some cleaning up before terminating.

*Example (all are equivalent):*

```
kill <pid>
kill -15 <pid>
kill -TERM <pid>
kill -s TERM <pid>
```

A more forceful signal would be the `KILL (9)` signal, which forces the process to terminate immediately.

*Example:*

```
kill -9 <pid>
kill -KILL <pid>
kill -s KILL <pid>
```

For more information and a complete list of signals, run `man kill`.

With `kill` you have to specify the target process by its process ID. The `killall` command does essentially the same, with the main difference being that it lets you specify target processes by their names. See `man killall` for details.

Comment: You may also want to look into `pgrep` and `pkill`

Comment: @anothermode - That's a fantastic response. Thank you for all the details. That raises one other question then: If I send any of the TERM/15 examples you gave, what happens if for some reason it fails? Does it, after some delay, resort to a force quit style termination? Or just give up? Or perhaps the kill process just keeps trying and doesn't terminate itself until success? Or ...? Thanks again for a thorough response!

Comment: As far as I know, `kill` just sends the `TERM` signal once and that's it. It's a rather low-level command that doesn't have much "intelligence" built in. You can think of sending a `TERM` signal as asking the receiving process to please shut down and then walk away. It can very well happen that the receiving processes misbehaves by not reacting to the signal in any way for some reason. With the `KILL` signal on the other hand, the Kernel forcefully cancels execution of the process. But I'm not a Kernel programmer, so take this information with a bit of caution.

Comment: Ok... sounds good.  Thanks for all the detail and clarity. Very much appreciated!

Comment: To clarify, you can (and if you are sure), run the killall command like this to force quit all processes tied to GarageBand or the name of the process:
`killall -KILL GarageBand`